# OpenAM HTTP Status 500

Tags: session, nullpointerexception, single-sign-on, agent, openam

I need some help :)

I am currently setting up partners for our SSO.

We are using OpenAm . 
So we are the hosted service provider, and I set up the Identity provider - our partner.

We have successful configuration but for this one I am running into a wall :/

It is SAML2.0,
Agent is installed on tomcat 7 and the communication seems fine.

When our partner is sending us a request he gets :

```
    HTTP 500


    Exception: 

    javax.servlet.ServletException : AMSetupFilter.doFilter
        com.sun.identify.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java 121)

    Root cause:

    java.lang.NullPointerException

    com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPACSUtils.processResponse(SPACSUtils.java:1158)
    org.apache.jsp.saml2.jsp.spAssertionConsumer_jsp._jspService(spAssertionConsumer_jsp)

   .....

   com.sun.identify.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter)
```

In the log I have :
**For SSO server catalina.out :**

```
   Nov 26, 2013 4:52:22 PM com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.signature.Reference verify
    INFO: Verification successful for URI "#_6cf47d3b-f425-4a10-aeb1-fa20cf763387"
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPACSUtils.processResponse(SPACSUtils.java:1158)
        at org.apache.jsp.saml2.jsp.spAssertionConsumer_jsp._jspService(spAssertionConsumer_jsp.java:224)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        ... 21 more
```

**In the Session log of openAm:**

```
        CookieMode is:true
        SessionID(HttpServletRequest) : is forward = null
        getSidFromQuery: request =org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@b1a7a0
        getSidFromQuery: sid =null
        before decoding getSidFromURL:sidString=null
        after decoding: getSidFromURL:sidString=null
        could not create SSOToken from HttpRequest
        com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Invalid session ID.
            at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1089)
            at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:92)
            at com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager.createSSOToken(SSOTokenManager.java:241)
            at com.sun.identity.plugin.session.impl.FMSessionProvider.getSession(FMSessionProvider.java:408)
            at org.apache.jsp.saml2.jsp.spAssertionConsumer_jsp._jspService(spAssertionConsumer_jsp.java:202)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
            ...
```

**And probably the most interesting, the Federation log:**

```
SPACSUtils.getResponse: got response= (give me a proper xml response)
**FMSessionProvider.getSession: Could not get the session from the HTTP request: Invalid session ID.
spAssertionConsumer.jsp: Token is null.Invalid session ID.**
SPACSUtils.processResponse: Response : com.sun.identity.saml2.protocol.impl.ResponseImpl@1262e43
SAML2Utils.getSPAdapterClass: get SPAdapter for ***
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : realm - /***
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : hostEntityId - ***
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : entityRole - SPRole
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : attrName - spAdapter
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : realm - /***
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : hostEntityId -***
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : entityRole - SPRole
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : attrName - spAdapter
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityConfig: cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig: got entity config from SAML2MetaCache: ***
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig: values=com.sun.xml.bind.util.ListImpl@1f
SAML2Utils.getSPAdapterClass: get SPAdapter class 
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityConfig: cacheKey = /***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig: got entity config from SAML2MetaCache: ***
ConfigurationInstanceImpl.getAllConfigurationNames: realm = /***, componentName = LIBCOT
CircleOfDescriptorCache:getCircleOfTrust:cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityConfig: cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig: got entity config from SAML2MetaCache: ***
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityDescriptor: cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityDescriptor: got descriptor from SAML2MetaCache ***
SAML2Utils:getWantPOSTResponseSigned : realm - /***
SAML2Utils:getWantPOSTResponseSigned : hostEntityId - ***
SAML2Utils:getWantPOSTResponseSigned : entityRole - SPRole
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : realm - /***
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : hostEntityId -***
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : entityRole - SPRole
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : attrName - wantPOSTResponseSigned
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : realm - /***
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : hostEntityId - ***
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : entityRole - SPRole
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : attrName - wantPOSTResponseSigned
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityConfig: cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig: got entity config from SAML2MetaCache: ***
getAttributeValueFromSSOConfig: values=com.sun.xml.bind.util.ListImpl@5cb1942
SAML2Utils.verifyResponse:binding is :urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityConfig: cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig: got entity config from SAML2MetaCache: ***
ConfigurationInstanceImpl.getAllConfigurationNames: realm = /***, componentName = LIBCOT
CircleOfDescriptorCache:getCircleOfTrust:cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityDescriptor: cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityDescriptor: got descriptor from SAML2MetaCache ***
FMSigProvider.verify: The cert contained in the document is the same as the one being passed in.
validateCertificate :  CRL check is not configured. Just return it is good.
FMSigProvider.verify: Signature verification successful.
SAML2Utils.isBearerSubjectConfirmation:timeskew = 300
AuthContext Class Name is :com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : realm - /***
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : hostEntityId - ***
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : entityRole - SPRole
getAllAttributeValueFromSSOConfig : attrName - spAuthncontextClassrefMapping
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityConfig: cacheKey = ***, found = true
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig: got entity config from SAML2MetaCache: ***
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper: List:com.sun.xml.bind.util.ListImpl@8d71dc68
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper.getAuthnCtxFromSPConfig: AuthLevel is 0
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper:hostEntityID:***
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper:realm:/***
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper:MAP:{default=0, urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport=0, defaultClassRef=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport}
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper:HASH:{***={default=0, urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport=0, defaultClassRef=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport}}
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper:authnClRef:urn:federation:authentication:windows
DefaultSPAuthnContextMapper:authLevel :0
SAML2Utils.fillMap: Found valid authentication assertion.
SPACSUtils.processResponse: Assertions : [com.sun.identity.saml2.assertion.impl.AssertionImpl@1f2c081]
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig: got entity config from SAML2MetaCache: 
DefaultAccountMapper.constructor: 
DefaultLibrarySPAccountMapper.constructor: 
DefaultSPAccountMapper.constructor: 
SPACSUtils.getSPAccountMapper: mapper = com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultSPAccountMapper
DefaultSPAttributeMapper.constructor
SAML2MetaCache.getEntityDescriptor: cacheKey =, found = true
```

Comment: When providing stacktraces it is usually beneficial to also provide product version, so people can actually match it up with the code.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder :) . OpenAM 10.1.0-Xpress. We identified that this error is most likely from an error of our partner  request (trimmed too much information !).  I am trying to see if there is any way of send a request manually (be the idp ) rather than waiting on our partner to send us request so we can test our sso configuration. I tried with :   `<form id="theform" action="https://ssotest/sp/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp" method="post"> ...`  But it does not seem to work ! I get an authentication error (null pointer)

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace suggests that there was no NameID element defined in the SAML response for some reason, most likely this is a bug in the IdP. The Federation debug log on message level should contain all the details about the SAML response, I would suggest to turn up logging level and have a look there.

If you want to reproduce the HTTP 500, then you should send the SAML response manually to the SSOPOST endpoint (see AssertionConsumerService elements in the SAML metadata).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It makes sense. Thank you for the details :)
We noticed that this issue was because our idp partner trimmed the request a little bit to much !!

So this issue is gone, we actually know are able to land on our application page - We have a SSO SUCCESS in the federation log.

But in the session we get :

```
cookieMode is :true
CookieMode is:true
SessionID(HttpServletRequest) : is forward = null
cookieMode is :true
CookieMode is:true
Running sendEvent, type = 0
Session.isPollingEnabled is false
Session Cache cleanup is set to true
Session.isPollingEnabled is false
Session Cache cleanup is set to true
Running sendEvent, type = 0
Session.isPollingEnabled is false
Session Cache cleanup is set to true
Session.isPollingEnabled is false
Session Cache cleanup is set to true
SessionID(HttpServletRequest) : is forward = null
getSidFromQuery: request =org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@84b1e0
getSidFromQuery: sid =null
before decoding getSidFromURL:sidString=null
after decoding: getSidFromURL:sidString=null
could not create SSOToken from HttpRequest
com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Invalid session ID.
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1089)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:92)
    at com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager.createSSOToken(SSOTokenManager.java:241)
    at com.sun.identity.plugin.session.impl.FMSessionProvider.getSession(FMSessionProvider.java:408)


SessionID(HttpServletRequest) : is forward = null
getSidFromQuery: request =org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@84b1e0
getSidFromQuery: sid =null
before decoding getSidFromURL:sidString=null
after decoding: getSidFromURL:sidString=null
could not create SSOToken from HttpRequest
com.iplanet.dpro.session.SessionException: Invalid session ID.
    at com.iplanet.dpro.session.Session.getSession(Session.java:1089)
    at com.iplanet.sso.providers.dpro.SSOProviderImpl.createSSOToken(SSOProviderImpl.java:92)
    at com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager.createSSOToken(SSOTokenManager.java:241)
```

And so in our application, we try to get the USER_SESSION from the http request, but it is null so we get stuck on the login page of our application :/